# On linux, what are the recommended extension for access control lists ACL?

Tags: linux, access-control-list

I have read many HowTo's, e-books, internet pages, etc, about the use of ACLs in programs like iptables, squid, etc. on linux
In the examples, they use the following file extensions:

```
file.lst
file.acl
file.txt
file (no extension)
```

In the examples, the content of the ACLs is varied (urls, IP addresses, MAC addresses, etc.)

question: On linux, what are the recommended extension for access control lists ACLs for these purposes and for these contents?

thanks in advanced

Comment: Normally, linux does not care about file extensions. you can use a extension you like, except if a Program requires a specific file that the author implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No recommended extensions**

In UNIX/Linux extensions are (in 99.99% of the cases) only for human convenience. So use any extension you like.